# How to call SiteAssets From Inside Another SiteAsset

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, jquery

I am using `HillBillyForm.js` by [Mark Rackley](http://www.markrackley.net/2013/08/29/easy-custom-layouts-for-default-sharepoint-forms/) to customise a couple of forms:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //loop through all the spans in the custom layout        
        $("span.hillbillyForm").each(function()
        {
            //get the display name from the custom layout
            displayName = $(this).attr("data-displayName");

            displayName  = displayName.replace(/&(?!amp;)/g,'&amp;');
            elem = $(this);

            //find the corresponding field from the default form and move it
            //into the custom layout
            $("table.ms-formtable td").each(function(){
                if (this.innerHTML.indexOf('FieldName="'+displayName+'"') != -1){
                    $(this).contents().appendTo(elem);                  
                }                 
            }); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Where I have saved the above in `hillbillyForm.js`

This is working great, but I recently came across a problem where some of our users who do not have internet access need to use these forms.

The issue is that that `HillBillyForm` requires `JQuery` to work, but I can't use the CDN due to lack of internet connectivity.

My solution is to include the raw `JQuery` code in `HillBillyForm.js`, and this does work. However, I feel it would be a lot neater if I could add this as a separate file, say `jquery-1.10.1.js` into my `SiteAssets` and call it from `HillBillyform.js`.

I have tried adding the following lines to `HillBillyForm.js` after creating `jquery-1.10.1.js` in `SiteAssets`:

```
<script src="../../SiteAssets/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>

<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>

<script src="SiteAssets/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://server/Knowledge/RISK/Expert/SiteAssets/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://server/Knowledge/RISK/Expert/SiteAssets/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
```

However none of these appear to work (I get a null-reference error in the same place as when there is no `Jquery` at all).

So my question is, how can I call a `SiteAsset` file from another file in `SiteAssets`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that

- The Parent Site URL is : `http://SPQassas/`
- The SubSite URL is : `http://SPQassas/TeamSite`

If your script file has been located at site asset library of the same **subsite** `http://SPQassas/TeamSite` , use the following

```
<script src="../SiteAssets/cookies.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If your script file has been located at site asset library of the **parent site** `http://SPQassas/` and you need to use it in your subsite `http://SPQassas/TeamSite`, use the following

```
<script src="../../SiteAssets/cookies.js" type="text/javascript">
```

If it still not working , so the issue is not related to the path it's related to the JS file itself, try to use another JS file with the above relative path guides and check if it's worked or not.

Comment: I have tried these suggestions without any success. The only way I can get it to work is if I directly past the raw `JQuery` code into `hillbillyForm.js` inside some `<script>` tags. I don't see how this can be caused by the JS file if the code works when pasting it directly into `hillbillyForm.js`

Answer (score 2):

This works for me using the Hillbilly tabs (in a site collection). If you are in a subsite, use the full URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

It should not matter that both the txt file and the jquery is in the same library.

For a subsite, it can look like this. It's just the full URL to the file location.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dev.contoso.sharepoint.com/contosoSubsite/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This code has the same effect as my other attempts. Could you please let me know how I can find the "full URL" for `SiteAssets`? (I think I may be in a subsite)

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks `Christoffer`, I have tried including the full literal path but without any luck (this is using an account which will always have internet access). I included the new attempts in my question but will keep trying variations ...